# Set expire date in UTC time format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Need to set expire date of item as present date till midnight as shown below in UTC format.

"2021-05-28T23:59:59Z"

Any way to do this?

Comment: What is the required precision here? If the desired precision is down to ticks, then you would need `2021-05-28T23:59:59.9999999Z`, or is seconds enough?

Comment: What do you mean by "of item"? How is the expiry date expressed in whatever API you're using? Is it deemed as inclusive or exclusive? We need a *lot* more information before we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString("o")
```

The output of above is

`2021-05-28T23:59:59.0000000Z`

I guess this is what u need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentUtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine($"Current UTC Date: {currentUtcDate:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}");

var expiryDate = new DateTime(currentUtcDate.Year, currentUtcDate.Month, currentUtcDate.Day, 23, 59, 59);
Console.WriteLine($"Expiry UTC Date: {expiryDate:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}");
```

Note that "shashank shekhar" use of the date format operator "o" is probably a more useful approach for formatting the date.  However, the solution above follows your requested date/time format.